# How close can we get to true OOP-like member functions in C?

Tags: c, oop, syntax

I am curious about how close we can feasibly get to "Object-Oriented Programming" in C (a notoriously non-OOP language).

Here's what I've got so far (similar to [this post from a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642830/can-i-define-a-function-inside-a-c-structure)):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 16

typedef struct Person {
    unsigned age;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];

    // "Member functions"
    void (*set_age)(struct Person *const p, const unsigned new_age);
    void (*set_name)(struct Person *const p, const char name[]);
    void (*print)(const struct Person *const p);
} Person;


void __Person__set_age(Person *const p, const unsigned new_age) {
    p->age = new_age;
}

void __Person__set_name(Person *const p, const char name[]) {
    assert(strlen(name) <= MAX_NAME_LEN);

    strcpy(p->name, name);
}


void __Person__print(const Person *const p) {
    printf("Person:\n");
    printf("\tname: %s\n", p->name);
    printf("\tage: %d\n", p->age);
}


Person new_person(const char name[], const unsigned age) {
    assert(strlen(name) <= MAX_NAME_LEN);

    Person p = {
        .age=age,

        // Attach member functions
        .set_age=&__Person__set_age,
        .set_name=&__Person__set_name,
        .print=&__Person__print,
    };

    // Initialize name
    strcpy(p.name, name);

    return p;
}

int main(void) {

    Person me = new_person("michael", 22);

    me.print(&me);

    me.set_age(&me, 100);

    me.print(&me);

    me.set_name(&me, "bob");

    me.print(&me);
}
```

*Side note: Please forgive me if my string handling is poor, I have forgotten how to do it effectively in C! XD*

The code works, and we get the nice "dot" syntax, but we still have to pass in a pointer to the original "object" which defeats the purpose (it's easier to simply call `__Person__print(&me)`).

The goal is something like this:

```c
// ...
int main(void) {
    // ...
    me.print(); // automagically calls `__Person__print(&me)`
    // ...
}
```

My question is: Can we push this farther and get closer to C++/OOP-style member functions?

I am curious if anyone has ideas, particularly with how either clever pointer arithmetic or preprocessor macros could be used to emulate this idea. I will see if I can come up with anything, and edit this question with any potential updates.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a number of object-oriented conventions you can use in C, it's not even that uncommon, but it's really open-ended as to how you might go about doing that. Personally I think what you're doing is fine, but the leading underscores are not necessary. In C we're used to doing things procedurally, as in `Person_set_name(p, "name")` is how I'd expect to see things play out, not as in `p->set_name()` which is just wasteful due to all the overhead. Your "handy" functions are not all that handy since you still need to pass in `me` anyway. The C way is "procedural object-oriented" at best.

Comment: Why? C is C... If you want/need constructors, learn C++... At least that language will try to clean up after the programmer, executing destructors when objects go out of scope.

Comment: Remember if you get too far down this rabbit hole you end up inventing something like Objective C, so be careful.

Comment: It looks pretty much like most C written by people who's embraced some kind of OOP. It opens up for building really wierd polymorphism and changing overrides of an object mid-life etc.

Comment: I am always curious - why do people try to imitate OOP if they can program in C++? Use the correct tool for a task.

Comment: @0___________ If you come to an existing project which is pure C but you have a C++ background, you may invent something like this. I'm not saying it's great but it makes it feel closer to home :-) (I'm currently converting tons of C code written like this to C++ so I've seen a fair share of it)

Comment: @TedLyngmo "We're not in Kansas anymore Toto!" `:-)`

Comment: Aside: `__Person__set_name()` makes no allowance for the _extra_ NUL string terminator... Hmmm...

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: Also, `assert` is an utterly horrible way to check for bad data.  If someone passes a too-long string to your `__Person__set_name()`, the entire process crashes, possibly causing loss of data among other issues.  "You passed me bad data, **so I'm killing the entire process!!!!!**" is almost never a proper response.  And the code can be compiled with `NDEBUG` defined and turn every last one of your `assert` statements into a complete no-op.  Which, in this example will corrupt memory - another really bad thing to do.

Comment: If you want to see something that's OOP-like in C, look at how filesystem and device drivers are called in the Linux kernel.

Comment: There's an old book on the topic [Object-Oriented Programming in ANSI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) by Axel-Tobias Schreiner, dating back to 1993, and freely available online via the link given.  I got fed up with it before finishing it — the amount of work required outweighed any benefit for me.  There also seems to be an [Object-Oriented C (ooc) toolkit](https://ooc-coding.sourceforge.net/docs/ooc.pdf) on SourceForge.  I've not used it at all and hadn't come across until searching just now.

Comment: Sure thing, you just need to write a custom preprocessor that inputs `me.print()` and outputs `__Person_print(me)`. Just be sure to invent a catchy name for it. How about Cfront?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.

- I'm definitely not planning on writing code like this. I am simply curious if it's possible to emulate this syntax sugar.

- I should have been more specific: While I am curious about actual OOP constructs in C and how to implement them, I understand that "dot syntax" isn't directly related to OOP.

- Thanks for the resources! I'll check 'em all out. 

- This is a toy example and I haven't done C string stuff in forever so I'm not surprised there are issues, thanks for pointing those out for me.

- Interesting note about the underscore reserved thing!

Answer (score 2):

**Object-orientation is a way to *design* programs, not a way to write them.**

You need to realize this before you run off chasing some "OO features" which aren't actually related to OO at all. Looking at your program posted, it is not using OO design since everything is made public - for the same reason as a C++ class with everything public isn't using OO either. Either fails to provide private encapsulation.

As in turns out, OO is most often synonymous with good design and the lack of it with bad design. This has always been the case in C even before OO became fashionable in the 1980s and 90s. Before that, good C designers already used "ADTs" (abstract data types) which were essentially just a class by another name. Whereas the bad (non-)designers just hacked away aimlessly.

> Can we push this farther and get closer to C++/OOP-style member functions?

What you think is "OOP style" here isn't required by OO. And well, we can't have it in C either. There are some restrictions of C vs C++ here:

- There is no `this` pointer, so it needs to get passed along manually with the arguments. C has no way around this. It is inconvenient, but it doesn't prevent OO design.
- When you write a member function in C++, the compiler gives that one special treatment and makes sure that only one such function exists for all objects of that class. A function pointer in C doesn't work like that, you will get one function pointer per object, which apart from the waste of space means that potentially/accidentally it could even point at different function per object. Not really ideal.

  In fact if the struct is written as you've done here with 100% public members (which is *not* proper OO design in neither C nor C++), then the caller can re-assign the function to something else. Most of the time you probably don't want that, particularly if the function is supposed to be a member function (and not some user-defined callback etc).
- C++ generates "vtables" of functions for inheritance automatically, whereas in C we have to either do this manually, which is cumbersome - or use the function pointer model as in your program, which has the above mentioned drawbacks.

Furthermore the syntax `obj.member()` actually has nothing to do with object-oriented design as such - it is just a syntax which is commonly used in most languages with OO support. If we think a bit more in-depth we might realize that such languages don't necessarily always use that syntax either. C++ has operator overloading, Java has `toString` and so on - language-specific ways to call member functions.

So there is no requirement of OO design that a member function must be called with some `.` syntax. It is sufficient that for a class named `stuff`, you have a `stuff.h`/`stuff.c`, a struct named `stuff`/`stuff_t` etc and in `stuff.h` you define the public member functions using code prefixes such as `stuff_create`, `stuff_get_x()`. Private member functions sit as `static` in `stuff.c`. This is perfectly fine and correct OO design in C.

Similarly, "RAII" with constructors/destructors actually has nothing to do with OO either - it just happens to be a *very* convenient feature to have when doing OO.

OO design only requires 3 mandatory features:

- ***private encapsulation*** of data and functionality, where nothing is needlessly exposed to the outside world that shouldn't be.
- ***autonomous classes*** which only do their designated task and knows as little as possible about the surrounding program.
- ***inhertance*** including polymorphism which allows code re-use and defining interfaces.

The former two are by far the most important and apply to 100% of your OO programs, while the last one is merely handy in specific situation and not mandatory to use everywhere. Experienced software designers know that everything in program design ultimately boils down to relationships between modules/classes which are either "x *uses* y" relations or "x *is a* y" relations - inheritance is used in form of the latter.

Private encapsulation and autonomous classes is easy to achieve in C, by using the design pattern known as "opaque types": [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Inheritance and polymorphism can be implemented in that concept too. We want the base class to be declared as the first member of the struct, because that's inline with the convenient C rule allowing a pointer to struct to get converted to a pointer to its first member and vice versa. Abstract base classes are real easy to achieve since with the opaque type concept, the caller can never allocate an object anyway.

But inheritance/polymorpism gets clunky in C when we want "private"/"protected" parts of the struct. Using the previous model of member functions in a h file exposes these to the caller, so those are regarded as "public". In order to do private inheritance we'll have to do something like:

- `animal.h` public functions/constructors/destructors
- `animal_private.h` protected functions to be inherited
- `animal.c` includes animal.h and animal_private.h
- `dog.h` includes animal.h
- `dog.c` includes dog.h and animal_private.h

And then if `dog` should be inherited too, we'll have to create a `dog_private.h`, and so on. So it is perfectly possible to do, but comes with lots of overhead.

With this model we can also create pure virtual functions by having animal.h providing `void animal_eat (food* f)`, then using that function internally but without providing a definition for it. Meaning that unless some dog.c implements `animal_eat`, then we can't use the animal.h class.

Answer (score 1):

"Object oriented" does not just mean member functions, it also usually includes classes, inheritance, and abstract classes or types (like interfaces).

Even member functions aren't necessarily dynamic (through pointers). So if every ABC object has a `print()` method, but it's the same for every object, then it's simpler to have one `ABC_print()` function that you pass the object to.

In the cases where structs with pointers to functions are useful (e.g. the function depends on the struct's data), it can be done as in your example. But the typical C way of handling similar but different structs (equivalent to classes inherited from a common parent) is to keep the objects in different collections (arrays, linked lists) of the same type, which you can keep track of together, with a different set of functions applied to each. That can get a little messy for some designs, but if you try to fight the language, you usually get both a messy design and a messy layer obscuring what's really happening to someone familiar with C but not whatever other language you're trying to pretend to use.

It's similar to early days when Pascal programmers used to try to `#define` `BEGIN`, `END`, `:=`, etc. as `{`, `}`, '=', etc., which did not turn C into Pascal, but also annoyed C programmers.

Basically, when the language you have isn't expressive enough to match what you want to do, it's better to err on the side of clarity rather than cleverness. It reminds me of the Brian Kernighan quote "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Comment: I agree. My goal is not to use C in this way. I am just curious if it is possible for fun :)

Comment: Well, for fun you can abuse `#define` macros quite a bit. And you can get a bit closer to object oriented code if you treat source files as the classes, not `struct`s. You can put what is essentially the public interface and `struct` in the `.h` file, and internal implementation and struct with private fields in the `.c` file. Cast the public `struct` to the private one internally, then case back to the public one when returning.